# Sending jquery ajax post to multiple tables with relations(foreign key) in one button submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Hey guys I am using Spring MVC framework on the server side, and JS/Jquery, ajax on the client side, database is Oracle.

I have a form wizard, with 3 steps in it, and this form will submit all of the filled in data to multiple tables.

Here is what's working -> Inserting to the main table(Business Info table), everything went into the table as expected.

Note: The table is set to auto incremental value using trigger and sequence method.

Note2: All of the JS below are under one button submit event, I separated them to show which one is working and which one is not.

```
        submit.on('click',function() {

        var currentDate = new Date();

        var business_data = {
                ubiId : '',
                ubiName : business_name.val(),
                ubiStartDate : moment(business_start_date.val() + ' ' + '00:00 AM', "DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A"),
                ubiAddress : business_address.val(),
                ubiCity : business_city.val(),
                ubiState : business_state.val(),
                ubiPostcode : business_postcode.val(),
                ubiPhone : business_phone.val(),
                ubiEmail : business_email.val(),
                ubiType : $('input:radio:checked', businesstype_list).val(),
                ubiRegisterAgency: $('input:radio:checked', agency_list).val(),
                ubiRegisterSsm: $('input:radio:checked', ssm_list).val(),
                ubiStatus: 'P1',
                ubiAppliedBy: Index.getUserInfo().cmsId,
                ubiApplyDate: currentDate,
                ubiSsmNo: ssm_no.val(),
                ubiOwnerId: matrik_number.val(), 
                ubiOwnerYearstartBusiness: $('input:radio:checked', yearstart).val(),
                ubiOwnerPhone: student_phoneno.val(),
                ubiOwnerEmail: student_emailadd.val(),
                ubiOwnerStudyyear: $('#student_studyyear').val(),
                ubiOwnerFac: $('#student_faculty_code').val(),
                ubiLecturerId : lecturer_name.val(),
                deanId : dean_name.val()
                //nature : nature_business.val()
        };

        console.log(business_data);

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: 'home/umkei/ssuForm/create',
            data: JSON.stringify(business_data),
            contentType : "application/json",
            beforeSend:function(){
                showMetronicLoading(el,msgLoading);
            },
            error: function(){
                Metronic.unblockUI(el);
                showMetronicAlert('danger','warning',msgInternetError);
            },
            success: function(){
                Metronic.unblockUI(el);
                //console.log(d);
                showMetronicAlert('success','check',msgSuccess);
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the code in Spring controller,

```
@RequestMapping("/ssuForm/create")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public UmkeiBusinessInfo createSsuForm(@RequestBody UmkeiBusinessInfo umkeiSsu) {

    UmkeiBusinessInfo createSsuForm = umkeiBusinessInfoService.create(umkeiSsu);

    return createSsuForm;
}
```

However there are some other fields in the form that are required to be pushed to other tables which linked to the primary key of this main table(Business Info PK --> UBI_ID column)

Another table is called Nature_Business which have Business_Id column that acts as a foreign key to the Business_info table(Ubi_id) column.

How do I get the value of the inserted primary key, and have it pushed to this other table?

Here is what I tried in Spring Controller(by create another action)

```
@RequestMapping("/info/businessId/{ubiId}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public String infoBusinessId(@PathVariable("ubiId") String q) throws SQLException {
    UmkeiBusinessInfo businessInfo = umkeiBusinessInfoService.findById(q);
    UmkeiBusinessInfo businessId = umkeiBusinessInfoService.findById(businessInfo.getUbiId());

        JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
        o.put("id", businessId.getUbiId());

    return o.toJSONString();
}
```

Then in my JS file(which is not working, I got 404 in the console of the browser

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'home/umkei/info/businessId/'+ ubiId //(I think it has something to with this one??) I dont know what to insert here,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend:function(){
                showMetronicLoading(el,msgLoading);
            },
            error: function(){
                Metronic.unblockUI(el);
                showMetronicAlert('danger','warning',msgInternetError + '. Failed to load business ID');
            },
            success: function(){
                Metronic.unblockUI(el);
            }
        });
```

Below is the one that I'm trying to insert

```
    var nature = {
            ubtBusinessInfo: //here is where I need to insert the new id inserted from the above code,
            ubtBusinessListing: //here is the value which is selected by the user
    };

        //console.log(nature);

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: 'home/umkei/ssuForm/create/nature',
    data: JSON.stringify(nature),
    contentType : "application/json",
    beforeSend:function(){
         showMetronicLoading(el,msgLoading);
    },
    error: function(){
        Metronic.unblockUI(el);
        showMetronicAlert('danger','warning',msgInternetError);
    },
    success: function(d){
        Metronic.unblockUI(el);
        showMetronicAlert('success','check',msgSuccess);
    }
});
```

Or, is it my approach is wrong? Please someone enlighten me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a "," and the end of your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'home/umkei/info/businessId/'+ ubiId //(I think it has something to with this one??) I dont know what to insert here,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend:function(){
            showMetronicLoading(el,msgLoading);
        },
```

Try to add the "," at the end. Let me know if still 404

```
url: 'home/umkei/info/businessId/'+ ubiId, //comments
```

Comment: Its there in my code. Its just at the back of my commented code above because I am not sure its correct or not.

Comment: No, if you add the , at the end will be ignored, set as i said in the response. url: 'home/umkei/info/businessId/'+ ubiId, //comments

Comment: I did. The comment is not in current code. It is set just like you said. I just added the comment in the SO because I need help getting the ubiId value.

Comment: and still the 404? could you paste here which request is your browser trying to access? you can inspect that with firebug or some developer tool on chrome (f12) to see the network calls

Comment: I didnt get the 404 anymore, as I did some changes to my code, but I cleaned up my question, see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372701/get-the-current-inserted-idauto-incremented-primary-key-value-to-be-used-right

Thank you!